# Unicode conversion error with django

Tags: python, django

Hi 
I've upgraded my django version to 1.2.5 and my app stopped working. The error I'm getting now is as follows:

> Caught DjangoUnicodeDecodeError while
>   rendering: 'ascii' codec can't decode
>   byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not
>   in range(128). You passed in
>    ()

So far I've been unsuccessful in debugging this problem. The error occurs in:

> Template error
>
> In template
>   /srv/apps/shop_tools/templates/orders/make_order.html,
>   error at line 18

and line 18 is:

> {% trans 'Order
>   Form' %}

With the **trans** being marked as error causing.

Any idea with this strange problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your .po files, in particular the one for the current language; the encoding may be declared incorrectly.